# Why doesn't requested tile get cached in browser?

Tags: openlayers, wms, tiles, qgis-server

I'm trying to optimize the load time of a mapping project using QGIS server and Openlayers 4 and have a question about browser cache.

PNG tiles from tile data with URLs in [XYZ format](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.XYZ.html) get cached correctly and show up in the Networking tab with *Status Code 304 Not Modified*.

But tiles from a [WMS server](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html) get requested every time (*Status Code 200 OK*) and don't get cached by the browser. The request URL doesn't change and looks like that:

```
http://host.com/cgi-bin/ffr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/qgis/map.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=ocean&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&BBOX=-7514065.628545966,5009377.085697312,-6261721.357121638,6261721.35712164
```

Any chance to cache this tiles in the browser so they don't get requested each time from WMS server?